# Is there a way to set different CFBundleDisplayName for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I don't know why but in iPad, the app name can be displayed completely.
However, in I put the same app in iPhone with universal binary, the app name is truncated.

Is there a way that I can set different app name for iPad version and iPhone version within the universal binary??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just set the iPad-specific name in `CFBundleDisplayName~ipad`.