# How do I change what shows up as the name of my application next to the icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set different CFBundleDisplayName for iPad and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466858/is-there-a-way-to-set-different-cfbundledisplayname-for-ipad-and-iphone)

The title of my iPhone application is too long to fit underneath the icon, so I would like to create a smaller name for it. However, I do NOT want to change the actual name of my application. I know this is possible, I am just unsure of how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `CFBundleDisplayName` in the Info.plist

You may also be interested in this question: [Is there a way to set different CFBundleDisplayName for iPad and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466858/is-there-a-way-to-set-different-cfbundledisplayname-for-ipad-and-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Change the bundle display name in your app's PLIST file.